# @Formula input schema from application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Based on environment (dev, qa, prod) I use different schema names. My code uses @Formula annotation for running a custom SQL command and populating that field with the value. Is it possible to give to @Formula the database schema, dynamically so that I don't update the code per environment?

```
@Formula("select date from devSchema.table")
private LocalDate myDate;
```

How can i use an application.property instead of hardcoding the schema?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by add {h-schema} instead of schema name.

@Formula("select date from {h-schema}table")
private LocalDate myDate;